# I can't display error message using JSR303 @Valid

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, annotations

I try to display error message in my jsp's file, but it didn't work.

here my Model class, named EmployeeEntity.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class EmployeeEntity 
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name="LASTNAME")
    private String lastname;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="ADDRESS")
    private String address;

    @Column(name="EMAIL")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="TELEPHONE")
    private String telephone;

    @Column(name="USERNAME")
    private String username;

    @Column(name="PASSWORD")
    private String password;


    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getTelephone() {
        return telephone;
    }

    public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }
}
```

Here my jsp page

```
<form:form method="post" commandName="employeeEntity" action="add">
<form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div" />
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Employee Register Form
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">
                <fmt:message key="label.firstname" />
            </label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <form:input path="firstname" class="form-control" placeholder="first name" />
                <span class="help-block"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">
                <fmt:message key="label.lastname"/>
            </label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <form:input path="lastname" class="form-control" placeholder="last name" />
                <span class="help-block"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">
                <fmt:message key="label.address"/>
            </label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <form:textarea rows="5" path="address" class="form-control" placeholder="address" />
                <form:errors path="address" cssClass="error" />
                <span class="help-block"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">
                <fmt:message key="label.gender"/>
            </label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <label class="label-radio">
                    <form:radiobutton path="gender" value="male"/>
                    Male
                </label>
                <label class="label-checkbox">
                    <form:radiobutton path="gender" value="female" />
                    Female      
                </label>
                <span class="help-block"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">
                <fmt:message key="label.email"/>
            </label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <form:input path="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email" />
                <span class="help-block"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">
                <fmt:message key="label.phonenumber"/>
            </label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <form:input path="telephone" class="form-control" placeholder="phone number" />
                <span class="help-block"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">
                <fmt:message key="label.username"/>
            </label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <form:input path="username" class="form-control" placeholder="username" />
                <span class="help-block"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">
                <fmt:message key="label.password"/>
            </label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <form:password path="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" />
                <span class="help-block"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="<fmt:message key="button.submit" />" />
        <input type="reset" class="btn btn-warning" value="<fmt:message key="button.reset" />" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my xml file

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.howtodoinjava.controller" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />


enter code here
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="employeeDAO" class="com.howtodoinjava.dao.EmployeeDaoImpl"></bean>
<bean id="carDAO" class="com.howtodoinjava.dao.CarDaoImpl"></bean>

<bean id="employeeManager" class="com.howtodoinjava.service.EmployeeManagerImpl"></bean>
<bean id="carManager" class="com.howtodoinjava.service.CarManagerImpl"></bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

and here is my controller class

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "registerForm/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addEmployee(@Valid EmployeeEntity employee, BindingResult result){
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return "redirect:/registerForm/form";
    } else {
        employeeManager.addEmployee(employee);
        return "redirect:/list";
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me, and i'am new in spring hibernate

Thanks,
Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved..

I have update my question and include my jsp page, and the problem in there.

I can't display my error message because commandName in `<form:form>` tag doesn't apply camelcase from my model class name. So i change from "employee" into "employeEntity"

I found the answer from [this link](http://stefanhendriks.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/gotchas-showing-error-messages-with-spring-forms-formerrors/)

hope this question help you too guys...

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a validator class (e.g. EmployeeValidator) that implements `org.springframework.validation.Validator` interface which contain the validation logic. Apart from that you would need to bind that validator in the controller class where your `addEmployee` method is defined like following:

Let's say you declared the EmployeeValidator via the variable employeeValidator in the controller class (you can autowire by having it declared in your beans config xml), then you need to bind the validator in the controller class like below.

```
@InitBinder
private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(employeeValidator);
}
```

Then the validator would automatically call and set the errors in the BindingResult (i.e. result in your method signature).

For writing the validator implementation check the following links:

[Spring MVC Form Validation Example using Annotation and Custom Validator implementation](http://www.journaldev.com/2668/spring-mvc-form-validation-example-using-annotation-and-custom-validator-implementation)

[Validation Framework in Spring with Example](http://www.concretepage.com/spring/validation-framework-spring-example)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is it still need validator class if i just will give "not empty" constraint in "ADDRESS" properties? Sorry and thanks for your answer.

Comment: Did you get a chance to debug the line `if(result.hasErrors()){..}` to see if it is returning true at all?

Comment: Yes. That Else If block work properly. I mean when i input empty value in email field, so it will get in into IF block, but when i input something in address field, it will get in into ELSE block. It is what you mean? @Uresh . Thanks for your answer before

Comment: I guess, you meant, it returns true when value for `address` field is empty value. Anyway, did spring mvc redirects you to the /registerForm/form.jsp page or not? There is nothing here to assess what's happening in the relevant .jsp file.